# What do these lines do when computing Mandelbrot set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, complex-numbers, mandelbrot

Not sure if this should go into Math Stack Exchange or here, but I can move it if needed. I have this piece of code that generates two matrices from which the Mandelbrot set is plottable and I am trying to understand it.

```
def mandelbrot_set(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, xn, yn, maxiter, horizon=2.0):
    X = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, xn, dtype=np.float32)
    Y = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, yn, dtype=np.float32)
    C = X + Y[:, None]*1j
    N = np.zeros(C.shape, dtype=int)
    Z = np.zeros(C.shape, np.complex64)
    for n in range(maxiter):
        I = np.less(abs(Z), horizon)
        N[I] = n
        Z[I] = Z[I]**2 + C[I]
    N[N == maxiter-1] = 0
    return Z, N
```

1. `I = np.less(abs(Z), horizon)`: This line seems to be creating a matrix `I` with dimensions matching `Z`. The values in this matrix are true/false. Why is this needed? What purpose does it serve?
2. `N[N == maxiter-1] = 0`: Is this line comparing the entire `N` with `maxiter-1`? This comparison returns either true or false, so then what would `N[True]` or `N[False]` do? And why do we set either of these two possible outcomes to 0 afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the mathematics of it, but:

1. `I = np.less(abs(Z), horizon)` is generating a boolean mask of True/False values for which elements of `abs(Z)` are less than elements of `horizon`.  This is then used as a mask to select elements from `N` where this condition is true, and later on also for `Z` and `C`, such that only elements where the corresponding element in `I` is true are selected.  Putting it all together, `N[I]` will give you elements of `N` where that same element in `abs(Z)` is less than `horizon`.  If you're not familiar with masking, see [here](https://riptutorial.com/pandas/example/29612/applying-a-boolean-mask-to-a-dataframe).
2. `N[N == maxiter-1] = 0` is setting any entry where `N` is equal to `maxiter - 1` to a value of 0.  Say `maxiter` is 3, if an entry in `N` is equal to 2, then it gets set to 0.  I'm presuming N is a single column/vector, otherwise this would throw errors.

Comment: the `N[N== maxiter-1] =0` bit is called boolean indexing: https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing . doing `N[I] = n`, where I is a mask, is actually following the same structure as `N[N==maxiter-1]=0` - they both have a mask inside the square brackets, only difference is that one is inline and other is defined as a variable `I`.